# BigQueryException: API limit exceeded

Tags: scala, google-bigquery

I'm using Bigquery Java API to run ~1000 copy jobs simultaneously (With scala.concurrent.Future) with WriteDisposition WRITE_APPEND, but I'm getting

```
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: API limit exceeded: Unable to return a row that exceeds the API limits. To retrieve the row, export the table
```

I thought this is caused by too much concurrency, then I tried to use Monix's Task to limit the parallelism to at most 20:

```
def execute(queries: List[Query]): Future[Seq[Boolean]] = {
    val tasks: Iterator[Task[List[Boolean]]] = queries.map(q => BqApi.copyTable(q, destinationTable))
      .sliding(20, 20)
      .map(Task.gather(_))

    val results: Task[List[Boolean]] = Task.sequence(tasks)
      .map(_.flatten.toList)

    results.runAsync
  }
```

where BqApi.copyTable executes the query and copy the result to the destination table then returns a Task[Boolean].

The same exception still happens.

But if I change the WriteDisposition to WRITE_TRUNCATE, the exception goes away.

Can anyone help me to understand what happens under the hood? And why Bigquery API behaves like this?

Answer (score 1):

This message is encountered when a query exceeds a maximum response size. Since copy jobs use `jobs.insert`, maybe you're hitting the [maximum row size](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs) which are in the query jobs limits. I suggest filling a BigQuery bug on its [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659) to describe your behavior properly regarding the Java API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if I set WriteDisposition to WRITE_TRUNCATE, the exception never shows up, so the 'exceed max row size' assumption may not be valid since the query part in both cases are the same.

Comment: Since WRITE_TRUNCATE overwrites the table data and you're not getting the API limit message by using this, then I'll suggest to [fill an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659) so the BigQuery team can review this behavior.